# How to prepopulate standard Lead field Phone by hacking URL?

Tags: fields, urlhacking

I am familiar with URL hacking and I can prepopulate a custom field by identifying the custom field ID and building a URL accordingly. *(The ID of a Custom Field is easy to identify).*

I'm using a custom button to open the standard "Create New Lead" page. However, I can't work out how to specify a standard field like Phone in the URL.

Is this possible? I'd rather use the standard Create/Edit Lead page if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Right click on the field in your browser
- Inspect element
- You will see something like `<input type="text" id="lea8" value="">`

**lea8** is in this case the id of the field you would want to include in your url as parameter.

PS: url hacking is not supported by Salesforce. You might want to look into [publisher actions](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=actions_overview.htm) to meet your business requirement.

Comment: Excellent. That gets me out of the immediate hole. I'll look at Publisher Actions in the longer term.

Comment: Just to confirm that this answer worked very well for me.